# Sessions for Android and webservices

Tags: php, android, web-services, session

I have an android and web-services written in php. The android has an authentication system from which the application sends the "username" and "password" to the webservice and it will return the user-id. I then use the user-id to request other information via the web-services.

In terms of good practice, the above method is not secure and I thought of using sessions. But I do not know how to use them? Can you guys give me some examples of making requests from the android to the web-services more secure?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You have two main options:

1- Communicate to your webservice over `SSL` in this case you can send the username/password as plain text since they will be encrypted anyways

2- Encrypt the username/password with the server `public key` so no one except the web service (who has the `private key` can decrypt the message)

If you want the entire communication to be secure (not only sending username/password) you can use a `symmetric cipher` algorithm (e.g. `AES`) because `asymmetric cipher` algorithms (e.g. `RSA`) are much slower and consume more resources.

Also, not that you will need to convert the `public key` to `DER` format to use it from android, which you can do with `openssl`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

If you are using HttpClient for sending you can store it in application object and use it for future requests

```
import android.app.Application;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class AppObj extends Application
{
  public static DefaultHttpClient davisimperialclient;

}
```

In your login screen you must create an HttpClient

```
AppObj.davisimperialclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost localHttpPost = new HttpPost(ApplicationLinks.login);
      try
      {
        ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList(2);
        localArrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", this.name));
        localArrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", this.pass));
        localHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(localArrayList));
        String  str = EntityUtils.toString(DavisImperialApp.davisimperialclient.execute(localHttpPost).getEntity());
        Log.e("error", str);
        return str;
      }
      catch (Exception localException)
      {


      }
```

if the login is successful you can use

```
AppObj.davisimperialclient
```

for making other requests

the object will exists till we exit the application